# publishing web apps in IIS getting different errors

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-10, iis-10

My project is running well in visual studio 2015. I published the app and upload in IIS. When I try to run the app, I am getting error as

```
The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located.
```

On searching in internet, I found that commenting this line in web config solves the problem. So I commented this line::

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
```

Then again I tried to run my project, now I am getting error as:
Parser Error Message: The file `'/view/global.Master'` does not exist.

shows at `Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/view/global.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="profile.aspx.cs" Inherits="myApp.view.profile" %>`

then I changed the code for MasterPageFile as ::
  `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="../view/global.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="profile.aspx.cs" Inherits="myApp.view.profile" %>`

Now I am getting error as::

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'myApp.view.global'.
```

Line 1:  `<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="global.master.cs" Inherits="myApp.view.global" %>`

I can not understand what is the problem with uploading my project in IIS. Why I am getting continuous errors? 
[image]

I did a rough fixing of my problem. Previously, I kept all my published files and folders in a folder and then put that folder inside wwwroot directory. So my folder structure looked like::

```
wwwroot --> myapp --> bin, scripts, view folders and other files
```

But now I've directly kept my published files and folders inside `wwwroot` directory. And now I can browse my app. But it is not the solution for my problem, what if I have to host multiple apps? Any help regarding the problem will be highly appreciated. Thank You!!!

Comment: Please share your application pool settings screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think problem regarding publish setting.
please try to check bellow setting.

[image]

Comment: give me anydesk

Comment: anydesk id :: 194 391 544

Comment: What happened? Did you get the problem?

Comment: didnt access your IIS. not able to typing on your pc.

Comment: can you see IIS on screen? if you can see, you can message me from any desk and I will do that. Please again connect. Thank You!

Comment: did you figure out the problem?

Comment: office lunch over..have to go..remind me at 9:PM INDIA

Comment: Please see my question, I've added my solution but it is not the actual solution.